# Appium error : [XCUITest] Error: Could not initialize ios-deploy make sure it is installed (npm install -g ios-deploy) and works on your system

Tags: xcode, appium

I got an error in Appium : [XCUITest] Error: Could not initialize ios-deploy make sure it is installed (npm install -g ios-deploy) and works on your system.

I try to run my test automation on the real device, not on simulator.

I am using Mac v10.12.5
Appium v1.6.5
Xcode v8.3.3

Can anyone help what could cause it please?

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually add environment variables when launching Appium Server programmatically. Maybe same in your case.
Try follows if you are launching server by AppiumServiceBuilder class in java.

```
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
builder.withEnvironment(new HashMap<String, String>() {
    { put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin: and any...") }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out latest appium desktop iOS setup :

AppiumDesktop1.1.0beta4 iOS setup - Inspector and Record the scripts,

Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_xHmofGgUE

If you face any issue please comment it.